Standard enthalpies of reactions involving multiple gases as reactants
I'm confused by the definition of standard enthalpy of reaction. Consider a reaction which has multiple gases as reactants, such as the one below which shows the combustion of methane.
$$\ce{CH4 (g) + 2 O2 (g) -> CO2 (g) + 2 H2O (g)}$$
When finding the standard enthalpy of reaction for such a reaction, is the total pressure of the gases in the reactants held at 1 bar or is the partial pressure of each individual gas (methane and oxygen in the above example) held at 1 bar?

It doesn't matter for a mixture of ideal gases.  The partial molar enthalpy of  a gaseous component in an ideal gas  mixture is independent of partial pressure and total pressure..

As @Chet Miller mentionned in comment, it does not matter for ideal gases but as a matter of definition : it is the total external pressure on the system that is equal to 1 bar to determine the "standard" quantities.
It is not necessarily related to the partial pressure of the gases participating in the reaction.
If you work in a container only containing the reactants and products, the total pressure of all the gases (reactants and products) must be 1 bar, but you could also work in the presence of an inert gas so the total pressure is not linked to the partial pressure of the reactants and products.
For ideal gases, the presence of an inert gas does not matter anyway but it has an effect if you must consider non-ideality.

Thanks! I found this definition in the book "Chemistry: Core Concepts" by Blackman et al.: "The standard enthalpy of reaction at temperature T is the value of $\Delta H$ for a reaction in which the pure, separated reactants in their standard states are converted to the pure separated products in their standard states, all at temperature T." That clarified things for me. But now I'm confused about the theoretical justification for this definition. Would the change in enthalpy still be equal to the heat released or absorbed in the reaction? Can it be measured that way?

It is measured, corrected to one mole of reactant reacted and all products brought to standard conditions [mathematically]. For equilibria electrochemical data or equilibrium data as a function of temperature is used.
